# If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure induced by a premeasure and $E$ is locally measurable, then why is $E$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

This is essentially Exercise 1.21 in Folland's *Real Analysis*, which states the following: If $\mu^*$ is an outer measure induced by a premeasure and $\overline{\mu}$ is the restriction of $\mu^*$ to the $\mu^*$-measurable sets, then $\overline{\mu}$ is saturated.

Definition: Folland says a measure $\overline{\mu}$ on a space $(X, \mathcal{M})$ is saturated if every locally measurable set is measurable, where a set $E$ is locally measurable if and only if $E \cap A$ is measurable for every $A \in \mathcal{M}$ with $\overline{\mu}(A) < \infty$.

I'm having trouble showing that when $E$ is a locally measurable set with $\mu^*(E) = \infty$, then $E$ is measurable.  (The finite case is not hard.)

Here's what I have so far.  Write $\mu_0$ for the premeasure, $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ for the algebra on which $\mu_0$ is defined, and $\mathcal{M}$ for the collection of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets.  Also, let $\mathcal{A}_{\sigma}$ be the collection of countable unions of sets in $\mathcal{A}$.  The hint is to use an earlier exercise: for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $A \in \mathcal{A}_{\sigma}$ with $E \subset A$ and $\mu^*(A) \leq \mu^*(E) + \varepsilon$.  So I obtain $E = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E \cap A_j$, where each $A_j \in \mathcal{A}$.  Then I want to use the locally measurable property, but it may be the case that $\mu_0(A_j) = \infty$ for some $j_0$.

Any ideas?  We don't have any assumption that $\overline{\mu}$ is $\sigma$-finite, for example...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $E$ is a locally measurable set. It suffices to show that
$$
\mu^*(F)\geq \mu^*(F\cap E)+\mu^*(F\cap E^c)\quad(*)
$$
for all $F\subset X$ with $\mu^*(F)<\infty$. So let $F\subset X$ be such and let $\epsilon>0$. Using the earlier exercise, we find an $A\in\mathcal{A}_\sigma\subset\mathcal{M}$ with $F\subset A$ and $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu^*(F)+\epsilon$ (thus $\mu^*(A)<\infty$). Now $E\cap A\in\mathcal{M}$, since $E$ is locally measurable and $A\in\mathcal{M}$ is such that $\mu^*(A)<\infty$. It follows that
$$
\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap(E\cap A))+\mu^*(A\cap(E\cap A)^c)=\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^c).
$$
Since $F\subset A$,
$$
\mu^*(A\cap E)+\mu^*(A\cap E^c)\geq \mu^*(F\cap E)+\mu^*(F\cap E^c).
$$
All in all, we have
$$
\mu^*(F)+\epsilon\geq \mu^*(A) \geq \mu^*(F\cap E)+\mu^*(F\cap E^c),
$$
and since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we get $(*)$.

Comment: Thanks!  So you don't even need to make a distinction between E having infinite outer measure or not.

Comment: then the set F would be dependent on the epsilon wouldn't it?